# invalid operands of types 'const char [35]' and 'double' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a problem with a string in arduino. I know that I can not put together different types like that. I have tried several conversions but don't get it working.

The following line is where I get the message "invalid operands of types 'const char [35]' and 'double' to binary 'operator +'"

```
sendString("Time: " + (micros () - PingTimer) * 0.001, 3 + " ms");
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, with you help I solved it. sendString(String("Time: ") + ((micros () - PingTimer) * 0.001, 3) + " ms"); works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** [This question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25125/why-do-i-get-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-error) is pretty similar but on a different stack exchange site (and the answer is questionable).

---

The problem can be reduced to the following snippet:

```cpp
void setup() {
  "hello" + 3.0;
}
```

It produces the following error message:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'double' to binary 'operator+'
```

Many programming languages support "adding" character sequences together, C++ doesn't. Which means that you will need to use a class which represents a character sequence and implements the `+` operator.

Luckily there is already such a class which you can use: [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/). Example:

```cpp
void setup() {
  String("hello") + 3.0;
}
```

The expression is evaluates from left to right which means that the left most type has to be a `String`, in other words:

```cpp
String("a") + 1 + 2 + 3
```

Is understood as:

```cpp
((String("a") + 1) + 2) + 3
```

Where `String("a") + 1` is a String and therefore `(String("a") + 1) + 2` is, and so on...